# How to using Javascript add a new html element when reaching particular breakpoint

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The idea is when reached a tablet or desktop breakpoint >768px using Javascript addElement method to add a Paragraph and input element to my html.
I've never done that? is it possible, and how so?

Thank you!

Comment: Just show or hide using media queries

Comment: I am trying something else? I am trying to add some Javascript interactivity to my page and this is not the same. I know this already.

Comment: So see one of the other dupes I posted. Reload the question. You can search for _insert div tablet_ or similar. There are hundreds of dupes